# ¿Crear un gráfico tipo donut con líneas delgadas y con texto e imagen en el centro con Chart.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, chart.js

Estoy tratando de obtener un resultado como el de la imagen: un gráfico circular tipo donut que la línea sea delgada y colocar un texto y un gráfico al centro. Estoy trabajando con **`chart.js`** alguna sugerencia ?

```
<head>
    <script src="http://www.chartjs.org/dist/2.6.0/Chart.bundle.js"></script>
    <script src="http://www.chartjs.org/samples/latest/utils.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="canvas-holder" style="width:40%">
        <canvas id="chart-area" />
    </div>

    <script>
        var randomScalingFactor = function() {
            return Math.round(Math.random() * 100);
        };

        var config = {
            type: 'doughnut',
            data: {
                datasets: [{
                    data: [
                        randomScalingFactor(),
                        randomScalingFactor(),
                        randomScalingFactor(),
                        randomScalingFactor(),
                    ],
                    backgroundColor: ['#fba901',
                        '#94d31e',
                        '#44c1c6',
                        '#87d9fa',
                    ]
                }]
            },
            options: {
                responsive: true,


            tooltips: {
                enabled: false
            },}
        };

    window.onload = function() {
        var ctx = document.getElementById("chart-area").getContext("2d");
        window.myDoughnut = new Chart(ctx, config);
    };
</script>
```

Esta gráfica es lo que trato de obtener:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Para modificar el grosor de las líneas de la gráfica, utiliza la opción **`cutoutPercentage`**. Según la documentación oficial, está opción traducida dice:

> Porcentaje de la gráfica que es recortada del centro.

Por tanto,

- `cutoutPercentage: 0` -> la gráfica no tendría ningún hueco en el centro y sería un círculo.
- `cutoutPercentage: (valor > 0)` -> la gráfica tendría un hueco en el centro según el valor indicado en porcentaje.

Un valor de `cutoutPercentage: 100` recortaría el 100% del círculo y no se vería la gráfica.

Para añadir un texto, o imagen, en el centro, puedes hacer invisible el fondo de la gráfica y añadir lo que quieras con CSS.

*NOTA: He cambiado la url a la librería, la que tenías no me funcionaba.*

```css
#chart-area {
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: transparent url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/t-160/so1.png) no-repeat center center;

}
```

```html
<head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.5.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://www.chartjs.org/samples/latest/utils.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="canvas-holder" style="width:40%">
        <canvas id="chart-area" width="400" height="400" />
    </div>

    <script>
        var randomScalingFactor = function() {
            return Math.round(Math.random() * 100);
        };

        var config = {
            type: 'doughnut',
            data: {
                datasets: [{
                    data: [
                        randomScalingFactor(),
                        randomScalingFactor(),
                        randomScalingFactor(),
                        randomScalingFactor(),
                    ],
                    backgroundColor: ['#fba901',
                        '#94d31e',
                        '#44c1c6',
                        '#87d9fa',
                    ]
                }]
            },
            options: {
              cutoutPercentage: 90,
                responsive: true,


                tooltips: {
                    enabled: false
                }
                
            }
        };

    window.onload = function() {
        var ctx = document.getElementById("chart-area").getContext("2d");
        window.myDoughnut = new Chart(ctx, config);
    };
</script>  
</body>
```

*Ese error que sale al ejecutar el snippet, es un problema de jQuery y no afecta a nuestro problema. Puedes ver a que se refiere [aquí](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326126/error-while-calling-jquery-show-in-stack-overflow-snippet)*